# Should we request a banner warning that AI-generated answers aren't allowed here?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

A few days ago, [it was announced on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/461068) that sites could now request banners reminding answerers that AI-generated answers are not allowed, like so:

[image: Stack Overflow answer box with a caption at the top stating "Reminder: AI-generated answers are not allowed on Stack Overflow.", highlighted by an obligatory red arrow.]

Since [AI-generated answers are banned on Writing.SE](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2545/23927), this banner could be of use to us, but community consensus is required before we can apply to have it. Personally, I'm unsure whether AI-generated answers are enough of a problem (in terms of quantity and handling time) to warrant the banner, so I'd like to know what the community thinks anyway.

**Is this something that the site could benefit from?**

Comment: I haven't seen any answers that seemed AI generated to me. Could you (or anyone) point some of them out to me and explain how you can tell?

Comment: We're not supposed to explain how we identify AI-generated answers, as people could use that knowledge to try and avoid detection. Suffice it to say that there are plenty of heuristics and detectable patterns we can use. I *could* point you to some examples, but they'd all be deleted and you may not be able to see them anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we should have the banner.

Although I'm not sure how effective it will be at reducing the number of AI posts, it can't do any harm.

Comment: The variant of the banner has been enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see a large number of answers that read like they are a cut & paste from Bard or Chatgpt. Being able to flag them for deletion seems like it would benefit the site.

Comment: It looks like you missed the [earlier discussion](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2545/34330) where we banned AI answers. You should be flagging answers that you think are AI (along with your reasoning as to why). This discussion here is only about the banner. (And I'd also disagree that there's "a large number" of AI answers here on Writing.)

Comment: @Laurel, oh. thank you. last I'd seen they were permitted. I'll flag them going forward